# Ruby Load Firefox Profile - OS: Windows 10

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to load firefox profile using the below code in (Ruby) and OS windows 10

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name 'default'
url="https://www.google.com"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox,:marionette=>true ,:profile=> profile)
driver.get(url)
```

But I am getting error :

```
C:\Ruby22-x64\bin\ruby test2.rb
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/w3c_bridge.rb:81:in `initialize': unknown option: {:profile=>#<Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile:0x00000007810630 @model="C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\AppData\\Roaming\\Mozilla\\Firefox/Profiles/razhtav0.default", @native_events=true, @secure_ssl=false, @untrusted_issuer=true, @load_no_focus_lib=false, @additional_prefs={}, @extensions={}>} (ArgumentError)
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-    2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/w3c_bridge.rb:35:in `initialize'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-    2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:51:in `new'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-    2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:51:in `for'
from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.53.4/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:84:in `for'
from test2.rb:25:in `<main>'
>Exit code: 1
```

Comment: Marionette does not support profiles in this way. I'm trying to figure this out my self. Some how you have to pass the options to geckodriver using 'moz:firefoxOptions' see (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/blob/master/README.md#firefox-capabilities) twalpole gives an answer here (https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara/issues/1710) that might shed some light on the situation. Otherwise I have been forced to use FF 47.

Comment: I have been getting the same problem , I think it maybe related to this issue https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2933